# There is something wrong in this merge sort

Tags: c++, c, mergesort

I want to sort an array .
SO i wrote this merge sort, it doesnt do what i want it to i.e sort, just stalls !
im going over the algorithm again and again, and i feel this is so correct, but no !
please take a look and tell me what might be wrong.

```
void mergeSort(int *arr, int low, int high){
int mid = (low+high)/2;
while(low<high){
    mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid+1, high);
    merge(arr, low, high, mid);
}
}

void merge(int *arr,int low, int high, int mid){
int i =low,j=mid+1,k=0;
int temp[50];  // should i new/malloc this with size of ( high -low +1) ?
while(i<=mid && j<=high){
    if(arr[i]<arr[j])
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    else
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];
}
while(i<=mid)
    temp[k++] = arr[i++];
while(j<=high)
    temp[k++] = arr[j++];
for(int x = 0; x<=high; x++){
    arr[x]=temp[x];
}
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: `while(low<high){` <- when do you expect that loop to end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void mergeSort(int *arr, int low, int high){
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    while(low<high){
```

if the loop is entered at all, it is an infinite loop since neither `low` nor `high` are changed.

```
        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid+1, high);
        merge(arr, low, high, mid);
    }
}

void merge(int *arr,int low, int high, int mid){
    int i =low,j=mid+1,k=0;
    int temp[50];  // should i new/malloc this with size of ( high -low +1) ?
```

Yes, you should definitely allocate the correct amount of storage.

```
    while(i<=mid && j<=high){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j])
```

That should better be `arr[i] <= arr[j]` to have a stable sort, though that doesn't matter for `int`s.

```
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    while(i<=mid)
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    while(j<=high)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    for(int x = 0; x<=high; x++){
```

That should be `for(int x = low; ...`.

```
        arr[x]=temp[x];
```

`arr[x] = temp[x-low];` (or use two indices).

```
    }
}
```

Comment: Most errors spotted. One missed: in the last loop indices into arr and temp are not the same (one starts from low, other starts from 0)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Missed that `temp`'s index should start from 0.

Comment: hey thanks, took care of the infinite loop, used if() instead of the while.

Comment: ohh yeahhhh, now i create a dynamic array 'temp' , the last loop was the big bug.. Thank you, i understand this now. However what do you think, is wrong with using temp[50] instead of '* temp = new[size]', i think when the function returns, the memory for the locals in the function will be popped.. and with new i have to take of it by delete[].. any reason for the preference ?

Comment: @KimKardashian Using a fixed-size `temp` array will crash hard if you're sorting a larger array. If you absolutely positively can guarantee that you never sort an array larger than 50 elements, `int temp[50];` would be okay.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but the stability of merge sort means its consistency with being time bound: O(nlogn), how does the '<=' change it ? adn why does it not matter for ints ?

Comment: @KimKardashian No, for a sorting algorithm `stable` means that objects that compare equal appear in the same order in the sorted array as in the unsorted array. As I said, it doesn't matter for `int`s, but if you sort more complex objects by a key - say you sort books by price - it could matter. One is not always interested in a sort being stable, but sometimes one is, and a mergesort is one of the stable sorting algorithms if one takes the element from the left part if the two compare equal during the merge.